# What is the shortcut to snap 3D cursor to grease pencil stroke in draw mode?

Tags: shortcut, grease-pencil, snapping, 3d-cursor, draw-mode

What's the shortcut for snapping 3D cursor to points on grease pencil strokes while in the draw mode? A yt tutorial showed the shortcut to be SHIFT+RIGHT CLICK but nothing seems to happen when I do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Shift right click should work while hovering over a 3D view window, even in draw mode, so check your preferences and make sure that 3D cursor is activated in the viewport overlays.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. Checking my preferences the shortcut seemed to be left mouse click. I changed it to shift+right click. But still it doesn't seem to snap the cursor to the stroke. In the object mode the cursor shifts fine to wherever clicked and the 3D cursor was already active in viewport overlays. Also FYI my default selection click is RIGHT CLICK (like how it used to be in blender earlier).

Comment: For precise snapping the fastest way is to press TAB for edit mode, select a GP point, press Shift S > cursor to selected, TAB again to return in draw mode.